# ASP connect to MYSQL error 80004005 "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP'"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp-classic, ip

Full error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (10065)

/test.asp, line 17
```

Attempting to connect to a MySQL database using ASP. Getting the above error, I'm not sure why. Apparently the error number means data not accessible, but it's not saying why.

Anyone have any experience with this?

```
<%
Dim oConn, oRs
Dim qry, connectstr
Dim db_name, db_username, db_userpassword
Dim db_server

db_server = "IP"
db_name = "DBNAME"
db_username = "USERNAME"
db_userpassword = "PASS"
fieldname = "FIELDNAME"
tablename = "TABLENAME"

connectstr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=" & db_server & ";DATABASE=" & db_name & ";UID=" & db_username & ";PWD=" & db_userpassword

Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open connectstr

qry = "SELECT * FROM " & tablename

Set oRS = oConn.Execute(qry)

if not oRS.EOF then
while not oRS.EOF
response.write ucase(fieldname) & ": " & oRs.Fields(fieldname) & "<br>"
oRS.movenext
wend
oRS.close
end if

Set oRs = nothing
Set oConn = nothing

%>
```

Values removed for obvious reasons.

Comment: the error message it's clear. The ip must be incorrect or something else related with network connectivity it's affecting your connection

Comment: Could be permissions too.  Try looking here http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/80004005-errors.html

Comment: "IP" must be a server name on your network. If it's not, then this error is exactly what it says.

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/q/14862777/1505348

Answer (score 2):

Ended up needing to allow the IP address on our firewall where the MySQL server is. Thanks all.