# "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" connecting mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp-classic, oledb

Due to some technical reasons, I had to change my database from sql server to MySQL.
But I am getting the following error, I cannot connect to the database..!

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

```
Set ObjConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ObjConn.Open ("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.0.96 Driver};SERVER=68.128.172.38;DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go with a sample connection string

```
Server_Name = "localhost" 'connect to the local  remort database server

databseName = "db" 'database name
mySQLUser = "root" 'user name
mysqlPassword = "admin" 'passwrd of the db user

ConStr= "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=" & Server_Name  & ";DATABASE=" & databseName & ";UID=" & mySQLUser & ";PWD=" & mysqlPassword & ";PORT=3306;OPTION=67108864;" ' Connection string
```

if that doesn't work, try installing the relevent connector for mysql [Select and download the connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)